# How to target select element and apply custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a bunch of select2 elements and my function `hideSelect2Keyboard()` used to hide keyboard on select2 open and close.

```
/* Hide keyboard on select2 open event */
function hideSelect2Keyboard(){
    $('.select2-search input, :focus,input').prop('focus',false).blur();
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open", hideSelect2Keyboard);

$("select").select2().on("select2-close",function(){
    setTimeout(hideSelect2Keyboard, 50);
});
```

It works fine; however, this function target all select elements as a whole that make me a problem since some elements have their own event handler `onchange` and `onblur` that they trigger unintentionally.

Therefore, I want to target my function `hideSelect2Keyboard` only to select element that is clicked on.

```
// hide keyboard after select value and drop down list open
function hideSelect2Keyboard(ID){
    $('#'+ID+' .select2-search input, #'+ID+' :focus, #'+ID+' input').prop('focus',false).blur();
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open", hideSelect2Keyboard(this.id));

$("select").select2().on("select2-close",function(){
    setTimeout(hideSelect2Keyboard(this.id), 50);
});
```

```js
$("#Gender").select2().on('select2-blur', function() {
  alert('gender selected');
});

/* Hide keyboard on select2 open event */
function hideSelect2Keyboard() {
  $('.select2-search input, :focus,input').prop('focus', false).blur();
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open", hideSelect2Keyboard);

$("select").select2().on("select2-close", function() {
  setTimeout(hideSelect2Keyboard, 50);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>

<label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Salutation">
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>

<label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Gender">
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
</select>
```

Then, this no longer works and no error in console as well. What was wrong, how can I target specific clicked element and apply function `hideSelect2Keyboard` work? Thanks.

Comment: can you make a fiddle from that ?

Comment: @SilentCoder, yes give me a minute please

Comment: till then I make a suggestion as my answer. but will edit accordingly with your fiddle.

Comment: So, to clarify, your problem is you want to target a specific element under a given class? :)

Comment: @C.RaysOfTheSun yes sure, I want to target specific element by it ID that was clicked on.

Comment: @HouyNarun gotcha. Please see my answer :)

Comment: @C.RaysOfTheSun it seems far from what I want, the second code snippet in question is what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#Gender").select2().on('select2-blur', function() {
 // alert('gender selected');
});

/* Hide keyboard on select2 open event */
function hideSelect2Keyboard(selectorId) {
  var ID = '#'+selectorId;
  alert(ID);
  $(ID+' .select2-search input,'+ID+' :focus,'+ID+' input').prop('focus',false).blur();
 
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open", function(){
// here you can think whether you pass id or not;
//var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
hideSelect2Keyboard('passnoid');
});

$("select").select2().on("select2-close", function() {
    var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
    hideSelect2Keyboard(selectId);
    var selectedItem =  $(this).find(':selected').val();
    if(selectedItem =="Miss"){
        alert("Do something");
    }
  setTimeout(hideSelect2Keyboard, 50);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>

<label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Salutation">
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>

<label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Gender">
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you provide a full snippet or copy from question? so I can test on it, Thanks

Comment: I am waiting for your snippet to copy. by the way I will give you a example

Comment: thanks I'm editing my question to add a snippet for you.

Comment: just check my answer. I'm trying to understand your question again. what you mean by this ? ` how can I target specific clicked element`, you mean the `<select>` element or the `<option>` inside the select ?

Comment: I tried to target `<select>` element, that I passed its `this.id` to function `hideSelect2Keyboard`, but it does not work.

Comment: check again. I get the id as `selectId`

Comment: by using `index` I could not know which one that has event handler or not by index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181715/discussion-between-silentcoder-and-houy-narun).

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass id of select field (`#Gender` or `#Salutation`) to function hideSelect2Keyboard so that I can set lose focus to classes under that ID as this ``` $('#'+ID+' .select2-search input, #'+ID+' :focus, #'+ID+' input').prop('focus',false).blur();``` . Problem is I could not pass ID of select field to my function that perform that job :(

Comment: Edited. check the answer

Comment: that's it I'm looking for. I can pass ID of select field I interact with to function process it in function. Thanks very much :)

Comment: I realized my jquery traversing `$(ID+' .select2-search input,'+ID+' :focus,'+ID+' input').prop('focus',false).blur();` is not correct meaning the those classes are not under ID but another sibling. That's another issue out of question. I will have to inspect element and re-write it correctly, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a specific element under a given class, you can try doing it like this:

```js
$(window).ready(()=>{
  
  function alertId(){
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     console.log(`${$(this).attr('id')} was clicked`);
  }
  
  $('.container-content').on('click', (e)=>{
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('container-content')){
      $(e.target).one('click', alertId);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container-content {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}

.inner-content {
  border: thin solid white;
  height: 40px;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-content" id="content-1">
    <div class="inner-content" id="inner-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-content" id="content-2">
  </div>
  <div class="container-content" id="content-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

When you run this, you'll see that on the first time a given div is clicked, nothing happens (because the click event is bound to the element after you click it). But, once you click it again, it will turn red and have its ID logged to the console.

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/yRXZOb) :)

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass id of select field (`#Gender` or `#Salutation`) to function `hideSelect2Keyboard` so that I can set lose focus to classes under that ID as this ``` $('#'+ID+' .select2-search input, #'+ID+' :focus, #'+ID+' input').prop('focus',false).blur();``` . Problem is I could not pass ID of select field to my function that perform that job :(

Comment: You want to assign an event handler to the children of the element?

Comment: yes, the classes children under the ID that passed through function `hideSelect2Keyboard`. the second code snippet in my question is what I am tried to achieve, but it does not work.